# How to know from ldd command which library is missing?

Tags: dependencies, shared-library

When I run ldd -r binary_file I get something like this:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf6d7a000)
```

and this seems ok.

However, I don't know what this line means, do I have the library or not and where is it:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7713000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`linux-gate.so.1` is a "a virtual DSO, a shared object exposed by the kernel at a fixed address in every process' memory"

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981862/what-are-ld-linux-so-2-and-linux-gate-so-1

Missing libraries are more commonly reported as **not found** in ldd output if I remember correctly